# Which Connected Component algorithm is implemented in GraphX?

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to know which connected component is used by [GraphX](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html#connected-components)? I have found it on the internet but the only result I got is the tutorial on how to use the code.

It will be better if there is a research paper about this algorithm.

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36945654/9776668

Comment: @themainhatch Thank you, I will check it.